# Something keeps overwritting my php version on my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I work for the guys at tecomm.ro
They recently have been hacked (yes it really happened and the whole website was replaced with some Chinese content and much more things)
Luckily, we had a backup and I thought that that was all.

Now, we are getting an error on WordPress dashboard: "Current PHP version is: 5.4.45. Recommended PHP version: 7. Upgrade as soon as possible!" This error keeps a lot of our plugins deactivated. I tried to update the php version from the cpanel, however, it was already set to 7.0. I set it to 7.2 it solved the issue but, after like 1 minute, it got back to 5.4.45. Something keeps overwriting our php version. I think it's some file that the "hackers" left on our server.

Can anyone help me with some ideas on how to get rid of this php version overwriting?

Comment: Try checking your .htaccess file and your wp-config.php file malicious script/code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try finding the file in which you can set the PHP version, set it to whatever you want and then remove all writing permissions from that file